# ASP DropDownList stops rendering dropdown/items after first item selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Thanks for your time..  My trouble has been something I am unable to resolve.  Hence this post..  I have an `<asp:DropDownList>` which is data bound in the code-behind.  Everything is working with exception to the actual drop down list of items only rendering on the first click of the control.  If I click outside of the control, the items/dropdown collapses and I can reclick the control to rereveal the items.  However, if I select an item, any subsequent clicks on the control do not result in the rendering of the dropdown/items.  I am so stumped here.  What am I missing?  Thanks..

Comment: We'd probably need to see your code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: try tagging this under asp.net. its not classic asp. you'll get more answers there :)